# Scrapy Spider returns only first product for every page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I uses scrapy to scrap products from amazon but It only returns first product for each page and go to next page what wrong with my code

```
import scrapy
from ..items import AmazonItem


class AmazonSpSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "amazon_sp"
    allowed_domains = ["www.amazon.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.amazon.com/s?k=laptop"]
    page_number = 1

    def parse(self, response):
        items = response.css('h2 a.a-text-normal::attr(href)').getall()
        print(items)
        for result in items:
            item_link = "https://www.amazon.com/" + result
            print("Hi I am in loop")
            yield scrapy.Request(url=item_link, callback=self.parse_item)

        next_page = f"https://www.amazon.com/s?k=laptop&page={AmazonSpSpider.page_number}"
        print('I am not in loop')
        AmazonSpSpider.page_number += 1
        yield response.follow(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = AmazonItem()
        item['title'] = response.css('#productTitle::text').get()
        item['image_link'] = response.css('imgTagWrapperId img::attr(src)').get()
        item['price'] = response.css('.a-price span::text').get()
        item['brand'] = response.css('.po-brand .po-break-word::text').get()
        item['model'] = response.css('.po-model_name .po-break-word::text').get()
        item['rating'] = response.css('#acrPopover .a-color-base::text').get()
        yield item
```

And screenshot of my output
[image][image]

Comment: What makes you say that it is only visitsing the first item?

Comment: I have checked url it scrap first item data and then page parameter in url increase by 1

Comment: If you are talking about the logs, then you are reading them incorrectly.  Try checking the actual file output.

Answer (score -1):

Scrapy has a different random scrapping order. It is scrapping all the items, even if it scraps other pages earlier before completing all the items of one page.
Please check the items in your final output, and compare with items on pages.

Comment: This is completely wrong

Comment: No alexander, why would you say that... I have checked the output in scrapy shell also... Although his selectors are not good, and can be highly improved but, it is getting items this way., and thats the only part to focus here, on fetching all items...I am also updating the screenshot with it,

Comment: If the OP were to take your advice it would throw an error in his code.  And even if he made the other additional changes needed for it not to throw an error, your suggestion would not solve anything, it would simply be an alternative way to get the exact same results.

Comment: Yes alexander, you are right.. There is actually no problem to solve here, he had just wrongly interpreted the scrapping procdure. Now i have updated my answer.